# What is the best way to render a Vuetify v-treeview with a very large number of nodes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, treeview, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify framework to display a foldable [Treeview component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#examples):

```
<v-treeview
 :items="items"
 :open-on-click="false"
 :open-all="false"
 :multiple-active="false"
 hoverable
 :active-class="'text_bold'"
 return-object
 activatable
>
```

And it works pretty much how I expected it to, but the problem is that the **items**'s children can contain up to several hundreds of nodes - and even if I load them more or less effortlessly, they get rendered by the browser too slow each time a parent node is opened.

Currently the UI simply freezes for some time when a user clicks a node with too many children. What I want is to display a loader or spinner while rendering the nodes takes place - but since there's no callback event in Vuetify Treeview for finishing rendering (what I have found was only for opening and async calls), I can't set a callback event for that.

Answer (score 0):

The best way todo is to load the children dynamically with `load-children`

> A function used when dynamically loading children. If this prop is
>   set, then the supplied function will be run if expanding an item that
>   has a item-children property that is an empty array. Supports
>   returning a Promise.

vuetify has an example of this on their page: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#async-items